# Why is the function cell.getTable undefined in Tabulator’s titleFormatter function?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Our client is insisting on a custom-styled checkbox. Ok, no problem, I'll put in a custom formatter function and return the svg/html required. However I have come stuck at header column checkbox.

I have been unable to access the table data to determine what state to show (and toggle all rows). The cell parameter coming in seems limited in its functions to `getValue()` and `getElement()`. Typescript defines more and it seems like it should have `cell.getTable()` etc. but these are undefined when accessed or logged.

Column code below:

```
formatter: function (cell: Tabulator.CellComponent, formatterParams, onRendered) {
  const checkbox = cell.getValue() ? checkbox_checked : checkbox_unchecked;
  return checkbox;
},
titleFormatter: function (cell: Tabulator.CellComponent, formatterParams, onRendered) {
  // console.log(cell, 'cell', Tabulator.findTable("#my-test-table"))
  
  const checkbox = cell.getTable().getRows().length == cell.getTable().getSelectedRows().length 
    ? checkbox_checked 
    : cell.getTable().getSelectedRows().length == 0 
      ? checkbox_unchecked
      : checkbox_indeterminate;
  return checkbox;
},
maxWidth: 25,
minWidth: 25,
hozAlign: 'left',
headerSort: false,
cellClick: function (e, cell: Tabulator.CellComponent) {
  const selected = cell.getValue() == undefined ? true : !cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(selected, true);
  cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
},
```

I have tried:

- upgrading tabulator-tables from 5.2.3 -->5.3.4
- getting the table via Tabulator.findTable however the way we've set this up with a svelte component means we're passing in the component to the Tabulator constructor rather than a selector string so this option doesn't seem viable (I have tried with an id set on the div).

Ultimately it feels like this should work with accessing table data via a parameter coming into the titleFormatter function but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this as a possible bug on the repo. Turns out this functionality doesn’t exist (yet) and will be added.

Comment: It has been added in the 5.4 release